# How to run a python script from its icon on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, python

I wrote a simple python script (with GUI in wx) and I would like to run it on Ubuntu, simply by just double-click it. I tried

1. chmod ugoa+x myScript.py
2. my script has the hash-bang line at the beginning (like #!/usr/bin/env python)

but still doesnt work, when I double-click it, it opens in python IDLE :/

Comment: Do you get the desired behavior when you run it from the command line?

Comment: @terdon: when I run it in terminal: `python myScript.py` it works

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% savy with Ubuntu, but to me it looks like you're using the associated program (through calling `env`).

I'd try changing the line to directly calling python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: thanks, but its even worse now: it dont want to open at all, even in pythons IDLE when I changed that line

Comment: What command do you use if you'd like to run it from a terminal window (without IDLE)?

Comment: I run it like this: `python myScript.py` and it works then

Comment: That's crazy. The hashbang is intended to remove the need to call a program like that. It should be able to figure out for itself what kind of script it is.

Comment: Could you try it with a more simple script? Maybe you just screw up the working directory or something like that. You should be able to just use `#!python` according to your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think Mario is on the right track here. Is python at `/usr/bin/python`? Check by running this command:

```
which python
```

Also, check if your script runs correctly without specifying python (that's what the hash-bang line is for):

```
myScript.py
```

Finally, make sure that the command run by the desktop shortcut (right click => properties) is one that runs correctly from the command line.

UPDATE

Since it seems to be a path problem, sdd the full path and command to the desktop shortcut. Right click => Properties and edit the command. If your script is in, for example, `/home/brian/myScript.py` use this as the command:

```
python /home/brian/myScript.py
```

Comment: yes, it is, look: `$ which python
/usr/bin/python` but it dont want to run, when I type in terminal: `myScript.py` only ...

Comment: Do you get an error message when running like that? And try running it with the full path: `/path/to/script/myScrip.py`.

Comment: It's a security measure. You can't run non-PATH stuff without adding at least a relative path. So try executing `./myScript.py` rather than `myScript.py`.

Comment: @BrianBrown, see updated answer.